# Automatically insert a new row with merged cells above a cell with formula

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating a spreadsheet for use inside our court system.  I would like the sheet to automatically expand as it is being filled in.  There is no way to pre-determine how many rows will be used.  I want new rows to be automatically added when the user fills in all the pre designated rows. That I can do easily.

I already have the VBA automatically creates the new row where I need it.

My problem is the new rows are not formatted the way I need them to be. In my worksheet, in the rows that are added, columns B,C & D need to be merged and columns E & F need to be merged.

How can I add that function to my existing VBA code?

Comment: By recording a macro and then incorporating that in your existing code?

Answer (score 1):

By converting the range into a list, most of this is automatically done. Zero programming. Just read the manual :-)

And by the way, avoid merged cells at any price ! Same effect can be achieved by formatting (center across selection), and avoids plenty of annoyances for range selection, inserting columns, autofill, etc...

Comment: @psubsee2003: right, I was on a bad mood. Corrected. Thanks ;-)